# An error from numpy.root via scipy.optimize.fmin

Tags: numpy, scipy

So I was working with a function that deals with the roots of a polynomial and I would like to find the minimum point of such function (for example via fmin):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def sumroots(t):
    c0 = t*np.exp(-t)
    c1 = t+1
    c2 = t+2
    z = np.roots([c0, c1, c2])
    return np.abs(np.sum(z))

fmin(sumroots, 1)
```

So ideally I should be able to fmin this function through the last line of the above code, but it returns me to an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-163-c7353335fcca>", line 5, in sumroots
    z = np.roots([c0, c1, c2])

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 209, in roots
    raise ValueError("Input must be a rank-1 array.")

ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.
```

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.
```

hints that we are passing a value to a function which expects a rank-1 array but
is getting something else. The traceback error message shows the problem is
happening inside the `sumroots` function. We don't call the `sumroots` function directly; `fmin` calls `sumroots` for us. So to investigate how `fmin` is calling `sumroots`, let's put a print statement inside the function:

```
def sumroots(t):
    print(type(t), t)
    c0 = t*np.exp(-t)
    ...
```

Running the code now prints

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [ 1.]
```

Aha. `t` is a NumPy array of length 1, and now the error is easy to reproduce:

```
In [164]: sumroots(np.array([1]))
...
ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.
```

Moreover, `np.roots` expects a [rank-1 array of polynomial coefficients](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) and instead it is getting a list of arrays. Since the NumPy array, `t`, has length 1, we can extract its single value using its [`item` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def sumroots(t):
    c0 = t*np.exp(-t)
    c1 = t+1
    c2 = t+2
    z = np.roots([c0, c1, c2])
    return np.abs(np.sum(z))

print(optimize.fmin(lambda t: sumroots(t.item()), 1))
```

prints

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 4.857178
         Iterations: 14
         Function evaluations: 28
[ 0.61806641]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it certainly does work.
With the modification t = t.item(), the function however is now unable to produce a result if t is a float (AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'item'). Is there a simpler way of dealing with this or do I have to put up with setting up a logic gate?

Comment: You could keep `sumroots` as it was and pass `lambda t: sumroots(t.item())` to `optimize.fmin`. I've modified the post above to show what I mean.